Can we always perform any complex quantum measurement with certainty?
Wigner's friend thought experiment, on some versions, involves making a very complex measurement on a laboratory containing someone making a more simple quantum measurement, so as to somehow "erase" the result of the simple measurement by recombining the full laboratory into a pre-measurement coherent state.
I understand that this experiment is practically unrealisable: this would require controlling and correlating an unthinkable huge number of particles. But my question is: is it theoretically realisable with certainty (without failure), or are there theoretical limitations at the fundamental level?
My intuition is that there could be principled theoretical limitations concerning whether the complex arrangement required for the measurement of the full laboratory to take place can be known to be realised in advance, and that quantum theory itself would predict that there is always some kind of uncertainty regarding what will actually be measured on the complex laboratory system, perhaps assigning a probability to the fact that what we think we will measure will actually be measured (presumably a very low probability for measurements that are very difficult to achieve), since, after all, measuring instruments are also quantum systems. Is this intuition correct?
More generally, is it theoretically possible to perform any complex measurement on any complex system whatsoever with full certainty (succeeding every time), and the limitations are merely practical, or does quantum theory predicts limitations regarding what can be systematically measured by an agent situated in the world, such as a success rate?
This aspect of the question concerns prediction of future measurements. Another aspect that I'm interested in as well concerns our knowledge of past measurements: can we always be sure  about what has been measured on a complex system (by performing a "meta-measurement" perhaps), or is there also uncertainty on this front?
I hope these questions makes sense.
